# Stripe Payment integration PHP JSON trouble with passing email through workflow

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, stripe-payments

I am testing strip payment integration in PHP and downloaded the test files directly from the stripe.  I want to be able to add "receipt_email" to the workflow.  If I define it directly on the create.php and that works fine, but the trouble comes when I define it as a hidden input in the form on checkout.html I don't know how to read it into the create.php since the client.js is fetching the create.php

```
   checkout.htm

   <form id="payment-form">

   <input type="hidden" id="email"  value="email@domain.com">

  <div id="card-element"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
  <button id="submit">
    <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
    <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
  </button>
  <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
  <p class="result-message hidden">
    Payment succeeded, see the result in your
    <a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
  </p>
  </form>


 client.js

// The items the customer wants to buy
var purchase = {
 items: [{ id: "shirt" }]
};

var formData = {
        'email': document.getElementById("email").value
};

  // Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
 fetch("create.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(purchase)  //I have tried using FormData Here but 
                                      need purchase also
   })
  .then(function(result) {
   return result.json();
   })
  .then(function(data) {
    var elements = stripe.elements();

 create.php

     function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
     // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
     // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
     // customers from directly manipulating the amount on the client
     return 1400;
     }

     header('Content-Type: application/json');

      try {
      // retrieve JSON from POST body
      $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
       $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);


     $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'receipt_email' => ??, //ok if defined here but I need to pull it from 
                                    input in checkout.html
     ]);
```

Comment: The Stripe API doesn't accept JSON. You should use the official [stripe-php library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php), but if you can't for some reason, there's a working example of how to format requsts in [the library's source code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/3febf22da8ed6a3b45842eac97d0fcece4d91e13/lib/ApiRequestor.php#L104).

Comment: This code that I have shared is taken directly from stripe.  There is so much documentation it is almost overwhelming.  I choose this method because it is the most simple approach I could find and it works.  The only issue I have is passing the email through this work flow.  I can define it on the create.php and it works fine also.  The issue is getting the email from the form on checkout.htm to the create.php.  This would probably be an easy question for someone who understands this workflow better than I.

Comment: Can you link me to the docs where we're recommending JSON encoding? I'll make sure we review them and get them updated if it's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder  This link has the custom payment flow that I am working with.  4 files are available for download and all of the code I have displayed above taken directly from here.  Thank you

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood your question. The JSON is coming into the backend (not going to the Stripe API directly). Can you clarify which field in the code above is the hidden one you're trying to submit, as well as what the JSON looks like on the backend when you submit?

Comment: Referencing the code above see the hidden input on the 2nd line of checkout.html.  Then Client.js see var FormData and creat.php see receipt_email.  My comments are there as well which explain my questions. Thanks